# How can i get the contents in UIWebview in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uiwebview, nsstring

I have a uiwebview in my viewcontroller which is used to display the epub contents ,How can i get that contents in NSString from UIWebView?
This code not working for me

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerText"];//may be `"document.body.innerText;"`
```

Comment: lol. same function, just changed name of that variable which he havn't even mentioned anywhere

Comment: @Naveen: as you can get the entire html, then look for the `<p>`.

Comment: frankly i dont have any idea about getting para element from html in ios

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate to ensure the loading web view before to display content:

```
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
   {
    if(!webView.isLoading){
       //if you need to get all ressources
        NSString html=[webView    stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
       //if you need just the content of Body
       NSString html=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
         }

    }
```